# php sql timer and redirect based on number of records in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am working on an application for racing and we want to display the finishing results on a web page or series of web pages on larger screen TV's so finishers can see them right after they are done. We have a MySQL database that we query via PHP and all of that works fine. Our challenge is this:

The TV display can fit 20 finishers at a time. What we need is a way for that first page of 20 to stay viewable as it populates however when our MySQL table gets to 21-40 finishers we need it to redirect or move to a page two. Then it would toggle back & forth between pages 1 & 2, staying on each page for let's say 15 seconds. Then when our result table gets to 41 or more finishers it would then move from page two to page three then do a one-two-three rotation, etc..

I understand the redirect timer in HTML and also how to select certain records from the database (such as 21-40). Right now I have (3) static pages that display places 1-20, 21-40, 41-60 but we are not sure how to piece this all together.

Any ideas/suggestion/recommendation would be very helpful. I have browsed Stack Overflow in the past with great success but this is my first chance to post a question.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best go-to on this in my opinion would be client-side i.e. JavaScript/jQuery where you query via AJAX through your PHP script MySql database and base on the response and number of rows of records you make it one, or two alternating lists.

Comment: Dino - yep, it looks like something with jQuery will be the best solution with all data on one page with a hide/show function of some sort. I have never done anything with jQuery so back to the books,,,,

Comment: Share more details, I or someone else might be able to help you further with jQuery.

Comment: Here is the link to download what we have. This does not have any redirects to other pages as described above as we have not figured that out yet:ftp://45.55.157.42:22/public_html/downloads/results2.php